# Cumulative multiplication in R with the addition of extra constants

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I'm new to R and struggling with the following combination of cumulative multiplication with the addition of extra constants. I'm looking to achieve the following in a dataframe:

```
Variable_X         Variable_Y           Variable_Z
X1                 Y1                   Y1*X1      = Z1 
X2                 Y2                   (Z1+Y2)*X2 = Z2 
X3                 Y3                   (Z2+Y3)*X3 = Z3
X4                 Y4                   (Z3+Y4)*X4 = Z4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dear all, I have now expanded the analysis to include a large number of columns of different values of variable X (1000+), for each I would like to calculate variable Z for (I'm essentially doing a Monte Carlo). Y is invariant and unchanged. Could any of these solutions be adapted for the larger data set?

Comment: Then the Rcpp solution is a clear win. Suppose your data frame is `dat`, where `x` columns are indexed by `ind`. You can do `z <- lapply(dat[ind], foo_cpp, dat$y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("NumericVector foo_cpp (NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int n = x.size(), i;
  NumericVector z(n);
  double tmp = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tmp = (tmp + y[i]) * x[i];
    z[i] = tmp;
    }
  return z;
  }")

set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(1e+6), y = runif(1e+6))
system.time(z <- foo_cpp(dat$x, dat$y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.016   0.000   0.014 
dat$z <- z
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only base R define an anonymous function to embody the iteration and then run it using `Reduce`:

```
transform(DF, Z = Reduce(f = function(prev, i) (prev + Y[i]) * X[i], 
                         x = seq_along(X), init = 0, acc = TRUE)[-1])
```

giving (for the input in the Note at the end):

```
  X   Y    Z
1 1 101  101
2 2 102  406
3 3 203 1827
4 4 104 7724
```

### Added

The gsubfn function allows short forms for function definitions and using that we could rewrite the above as:

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(DF, Z = fn$Reduce(f = prev + i ~ (prev + Y[i]) * X[i], 
                         x = seq_along(X), init = 0, acc = TRUE)[-1])
```

### Note

We used the following input:

```
DF <- data.frame(X = 1:4, Y = 101:104)
```

Comment: here are a couple of `tidyverse` translations : `mutate(DF, Z = accumulate(1:n(), ~(.x + Y[.y]) * X[.y],.init=0)[-1])` and `mutate(DF, Z=X*Y, Z = accumulate(2:n(), ~ Z[.y] +.x * X[.y],.init=Z[1]))`. `purrr` has a function `reduce2` handy to avoid the awkward use of indices but for some reason there's no `accumulate2` . there's an issue open about it: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/511

Comment: I think the awkwardness in the `accumulate` solution is not the use of indexes but the need to refer to the arguments positionally using `.x` and `.y` rather than using meaningful names.  The gsubfn package also supports function specification using formulas but it allows the programmer to choose the argument names. See added part above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a good old fashioned `for` loop is the best way to solve this.

```
dat <- data.frame(Variable_X = 1:10, Variable_Y = 11:20)

dat$Variable_Z <- dat$Variable_X[1]*dat$Variable_Y[1]
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dat))[-1]){
  dat$Variable_Z[i] <- (dat$Variable_Z[i - 1] + dat$Variable_Y[i])*dat$Variable_X[i]
}

dat
#   Variable_X Variable_Y Variable_Z
#1           1         11         11
#2           2         12         46
#3           3         13        177
#4           4         14        764
#5           5         15       3895
#6           6         16      23466
#7           7         17     164381
#8           8         18    1315192
#9           9         19   11836899
#10         10         20  118369190
```